In Crystal report's subreport inserted ole (pdf document) overflows to next page. How to stop?
We have to print company's contract terms (common 2 pages) on every purchase requisition. We have to print it in report footer. Have made 2 separate subreports. In it even if I insert the pdf of contract terms and align all details it prints first page of contract properly. On next page; lower half page of contract's first page is again printed and half page is left blank. This isn't needed. Same happens for 2nd page of contract. Means on last page the lower half of terms contract 2nd page is again printed. How can I stop this overflow. Even though full page seems intact (of page 1 and 2); still lower half page of both; overflows to next page. Matter is in pdf. So instead of 2 pages 4 pages are used.
I tried even copying and pasting the content of pdf to subreport apart from ole; same happens. Even tried the get the word file for pdf and insert ole as word; still same happens. If I copy and paste the word file contents; while pasting it pastes fully; however when generating preview it uses 4 pages instead of 2;with 2nd and 4th page having the contents of 1st page lower section and 4th page having the lower section of 3rd. On 1st and 3rd the terms print fully still overlap happens on 2nd and 4th page.

The pdf embedding can only handle one page.
You can handle that limitation by inserting each page separately.
Or you can use on the the 3rd-party Crystal Reports automation tools (see listing here). Some of these tools allow you to automate the process of exporting a Crystal Report to pdf, and merging the resulting pdf with other pdf files.
These tools can also handle other typical needs such as bookmarking, protecting, emailing, and printing the resulting merged file.

Even on inserting a single page pdf at a time; in each subreport (there are 2 such pdf pages); first page overlaps to 2nd  page. On first page preview is fine; however on 2nd page; last 8-12 lines of 1st page overlaps on 2nd page.
